# Problema com Regex no PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Tenho a seguinte função que serve para tirar caracteres especiais de uma string:

```
function removeSpecialChars($string){
  //List (Array) of special chars
  $pattern = array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/","/(ç)/","/(Ç)/","/(\'|\"|\^|\~|\;|\:|\°|\?|\&|\*|\+|\@|\#|\$|\%|\!|\\|\/|\(|\)|\||\=|\.|\,)/");

  //List (Array) of letters
  $replacement = array('a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U', 'n', 'N', 'c', 'C', '');

  return preg_replace($pattern , $replacement, $string);
}
```

Ele funciona bem, o único problema é que essa função não consegue substituir a barra, seja ela invertida (`\`) ou normal (`/`), e o cifrão(`$`), mas se eu colocar essa expressão regular em algum site para testar, como [coloquei nesse link](https://regex101.com/r/05oY1Z/1) funciona normalmente.

Alguém sabe o motivo de não funcionar no PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque dentro de uma string (entre as aspas), a barra invertida deve ser escapada e escrita como `\\` (conforme descrito na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php)).

Por isso, `\/` deve ser escrito como `\\/`, e `\\` deve ser escrito como `\\\\` e assim por diante. Outro detalhe é que o próprio caractere de aspas (`"`) também deve ser escapado e escrito como `\"`. Ou seja, dentro da string, o trecho `\"` da expressão deve ser escrito como `\\\"`.

Então sua expressão ficaria assim:

```
function removeSpecialChars($string){
  //List (Array) of special chars
  $pattern = array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/","/(ç)/","/(Ç)/","/(\\'|\\\"|\\^|\\~|\\;|\\:|\\°|\\?|\\&|\\*|\\+|\\@|\\#|\\$|\\%|\\!|\\\\|\\/|\\(|\\)|\\||\\=|\\.|\\,)/");

  //List (Array) of letters
  $replacement = array('a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U', 'n', 'N', 'c', 'C', '');

  return preg_replace($pattern , $replacement, $string);
}

echo removeSpecialChars("áçõ/\\?&"); // aco
```

No site que você testou não foi necessário escapar a `\` porque ali a regex não está dentro de uma string PHP.

---

Uma outra opção é usar [classes de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (delimitado por `[]`), tomando o cuidado de usar a *flag* `u`, pois caracteres acentuados [podem não funcionar corretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397725/como-retirar-caracteres-q-%C3%A7-e-g-da-tag-html-u-em-regex/397740#comment781448_397738) quando usados dentro de uma classe de caracteres:

```
function removeSpecialChars($string){
  $pattern = array("/[áàãâä]/u","/[ÁÀÃÂÄ]/u","/[éèêë]/u","/[ÉÈÊË]/u","/[íìîï]/u","/[ÍÌÎÏ]/u","/[óòõôö]/u","/[ÓÒÕÔÖ]/u","/[úùûü]/u","/[ÚÙÛÜ]/u","/ñ/u","/Ñ/u","/ç/u","/Ç/u", '/[\'"\^~;:°?&*+@#$%!\(|\)=.,\/\\\\]/');

  $replacement = array('a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U', 'n', 'N', 'c', 'C', '');

  return preg_replace($pattern , $replacement, $string);
}


echo removeSpecialChars("áçõ/\\?&");
```

---

Existe ainda outra opção, que é usar a classe [`Normalizer`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) para remover os acentos. Para usá-la, você deve [habilitar a extensão `intl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php):

```
function removeSpecialChars($string){
  $semAcentos = preg_replace('/\p{M}/u', '', Normalizer::normalize($string, Normalizer::FORM_D));
  return preg_replace('/[\'"\^~;:°?&*+@#$%!\(|\)=.,\/\\\\]/' , '', $semAcentos);
}

echo removeSpecialChars("áçõ/\\?&");
```

Com isso, os acentos são removidos de uma vez, bastando usar a regex para remover os caracteres especiais no final.

Comment: Perfeito, agora funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Mais simples você colocar tudo dentro de colchetes `[]` (*character set*, ou *conjunto de caracteres*), e claro, escapando as barras e as aspas duplas delimitadoras:

```
"/['\"^~;:°?&*+@#$%!\/()|=.,\\\]/"
    ↑               ↑       ↑↑
 escape          escape   escape
```

Agora eu senti falta de outros caracteres, como os colchetes `[]` e as chaves `{}`, por exemplo. Se for incluí-los, precisa escapar os colchetes também:

```
"/[{}\[\]'\"^~;:°?&*+@#$%!\/()|=.,\\\]/"
     ↑ ↑  ↑               ↑       ↑↑
    escapes            escape   escape
```

Comment: Uma boa ideia também, vai simplificar o código, obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielQueirozSchicora Eu ia sugerir isso, mas quando testei com `preg_replace` não funcionou, [veja](https://ideone.com/XMAdo1). Talvez eu esteja muito enferrujado com PHP, não sei se eu que errei alguma coisa :-/

Comment: De qq forma, é uma dica válida para simplificar a regex, então +1 :-)