# Como retirar caracteres q, ç e g da tag HTML <u> em Regex?

Tags: html, regex

Estou convertendo HTML para doc, e me apareceu um problema bem específico.

Palavras que contêm as letras `q`, `g` e `ç` quando sublinhadas, estão ficando com um resultado indesejado.

Eu pensei em resolver da seguinte forma:

```
<u>Administração</u>
<!-- Esperado -->
<u>Administra</u>ç<u>ão</u>
```

É possível e como fazer com regex?

Estou aberto à sugestões.

- A solução pode ser escrita em qualquer linguagem
- Estou convertendo o HTML -> doc com Libre Office
- O HTML está limitado a não usar estilos/css

Comment: O objetivo é ter as palavras sublinhadas às metades ? Isso parece meio estranho. Não seria melhor retirar o sublinhado por completo ?

Comment: Remover o sublinhado por completo não é uma alternativa. O objetivo é esse mesmo que foi descrito, tirando o sublinhado das letras q, g e ç a leitura fica mais agradável, pq o risco do sublinhado está cortando os "rabinhos/pezinhos" dessas letras. Acredito que uma das resposta dadas já resolverá, com tempo hoje eu testo.

Comment: Um dia (quando todos os browsers implementarem o suporte *full*) será possível usar [isso](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-skip/)

Comment: Considere marcar a resposta do @hkotsubo como correta. Pelos comentários, todas as dúvidas foram sanadas e ela me parece estar bem completa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embora seja possível resolver com regex, talvez seja mais fácil manipular o HTML usando alguma API específica para tal. Como foi dito que qualquer linguagem serve, uma opção é usar JavaScript:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('u');
for (let u of elements) {
    let parent = u.parentNode;
    for (let child of u.childNodes) {
        if (child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            child.nodeValue.split(/([çqg])/g).forEach(s => {
                if (/^[çqg]$/.test(s)) {
                    parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(s), u);
                } else {
                    let novo = document.createElement('u');
                    novo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
                    parent.insertBefore(novo, u);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // não é texto, preserva do jeito que está (dentro de outro "u")
            let novo = document.createElement('u');
            novo.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true));
            parent.insertBefore(novo, u);
        }
    }
    parent.removeChild(u);
    console.log(parent.outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p><u>Administração</u> teste</p>
<p>Outro <u>teste que agora etc...</u> lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Outro <u>teste agora <b>que</b> agora vai</u></p>
```

Primeiro eu obtenho todos os elementos `<u>`, e para cada um eu percorro os elementos filhos, procurando algum que seja do tipo [`TEXT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Node_type_constants). Se for, eu faço um [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) com `[çqg]` (qualquer uma destas letras), e coloco este trecho da regex entre parênteses, pois assim as letras [também são retornadas no resultado final](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Splitting_with_a_RegExp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result).

Depois eu percorro o resultado do `split`, verificando dois casos:

- se for uma das letras `ç`, `q` ou `g`, eu insiro-a como um *text node*
- senão, eu crio outro `u` e insiro o texto

Por fim, eu insiro todos esses elementos logo antes do `<u>` original (para manter a posição relativa, caso haja mais elementos irmãos no DOM), e no final eu removo o `<u>` original, mantendo os novos nós criados.

Também há um `else` para tratar os casos que não são *text nodes* (para quando há outras tags dentro do `<u>`, e neste caso eu só insiro novamente o mesmo elemento, sem modificação - mas colocando-o dentro de outro `u`, para que não perca a formatação).

Eu imprimi também o `outerHTML` só para que você veja o HTML final, pois na renderização do browser - pelo menos para mim - não ficou muito claro que as letras `ç`, `g` e `q` ficaram de fora das tags `u`.

Repare também que no terceiro caso, o texto entre as tags `<b>` não foi modificado. Eu fiz assim porque não ficou claro o que fazer neste caso. Na tag original tínhamos:

```html
<p>Outro <u>teste agora <b>que</b> agora vai</u></p>
```

Então o resultado deveria ser qual das opções abaixo?

```html
<p>Outro <u>teste a</u>g<u>ora </u><b>q</b><u><b>ue</b></u><u> a</u>g<u>ora vai</u></p>

<p>Outro <u>teste a</u>g<u>ora </u><u><b>que</b></u><u> a</u>g<u>ora vai</u></p>
```

Eu optei pela segunda, por ser mais simples (mas claro que é possível adaptar o código acima para tratar esses casos mais complicados).

---

Embora seja possível uma única regex para substituir tudo, esta [não é a ferramenta mais indicada para lidar com HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). A grande maioria das linguagens possui alguma lib (nativa ou não) para manipular HTML/XML, e com elas você consegue tratar esses casos mais complicados (como ter tags dentro de outras, comentários, campos `CDATA`, etc), que com regex é bem mais difícil de tratar.

Claro que, para casos mais simples (uma tag `<u>` com apenas texto dentro dela, sem nenhuma outra tag), a [solução proposta pelo Andrei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/397738/112052) funciona muito bem. Uma outra alternativa à regex dele é (em PHP, que foi o que ele usou):

```php
$texto = "<u>Administração</u>";
echo preg_replace('/[qpç]/u', '</u>$0<u>', $texto);
```

Ou em JavaScript:

```js
console.log('<u>Administração</u>'.replace(/[qpç]/g, '</u>$&<u>'));
```

Novamente, esta regex funciona bem quando não há outras tags dentro do `<u>`. Mas se tiver outra tag dentro do `<u>` (como no outro exemplo acima), aí [já não funciona tão bem assim](https://regex101.com/r/IolPTb/1/). Uma string como essa:

```html
<u>teste agora <b>que</b></u>
```

Se torna:

```html
<u>teste a</u>g<u>ora <b></u>q<u>ue</b></u>
```

Repare no trecho `<b></u>q<u>ue</b>`: fecha o `u` sem fechar o `b`, depois abre outro `u` e fecha o `b`. Bagunçou tudo. E a regex para tratar esses casos já ficaria bem mais complexa...

Cabe a você avaliar se uma regex mais simples já cobre todos os seus casos, e - tão importante quanto - se ela não gera casos inválidos. Lembre-se que uma regex manipula texto, sem se importar com a semântica e/ou estrutura do mesmo (então colocar `<u>` em qualquer parte do texto é indiferente para ela), mas um HTML possui uma estrutura bem definida e você não pode adicionar qualquer coisa em qualquer lugar. Por isso uma 
API específica geralmente é melhor do que a simples manipulação do texto (a não ser em casos mais simples, como já citado).

---

Baseado no que foi dito [no seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397725/como-retirar-caracteres-q-%C3%A7-e-g-da-tag-html-u-em-regex/397740#comment781456_397725) (você não quer que o sublinhado "corte" as letras), uma outra opção - caso você possa usar CSS - é usar a propriedade [`text-decoration-skip-ink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink).

```css
u.skip {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}

u.dontskip {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
```

```html
<p><u class="skip">Com skip Administração que agora etc...</u></p>

<p><u class="dontskip">Sem skip Administração que agora etc...</u></p>
```

Infelizmente ainda não são todos os browsers que suportam este recurso (neste momento, apenas o Chrome e o Opera suportam). Caso o browser que você use não suporte, segue uma imagem de como fica o exemplo acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo resultado obtido com a função "executar" o código aqui do stack, acredito que a solução será essa, assim que possível vou testar no meu código.

Comment: @Skywalker Fiz uma alteração no primeiro código, vi que tinha um caso que falhava.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você quer isso:

```
$texto = "<u>Administração</u>";

echo preg_replace('/([qpç]+)/u', '</u>$1<u>', $texto);
```

Essa `REGEX` funcionará caso tenha ou não os caracteres mencionados.

Comment: No caso das opções serem apenas uma letra, é mais simples usar `[qpç]`. De qualquer forma, acho que vale mencionar que isso só funciona caso a tag `u` não tenha nenhuma outra tag dentro dela - pois se tiver, o resultado final será um HTML inválido: https://regex101.com/r/IolPTb/1/ (claro que essa situação não é mencionada pelo AP, mas vai saber...) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo sim! Ele não mencionou, por isso eu simplifiquei. No caso quando eu usei o `[qpç]` no php ele retornou uma codificação errada. Não sei o motivo ainda. Por isso coloquei desta forma.

Comment: Ah, acho que o problema é o `ç`, que dentro de `[]` pode dar problema, dependendo do encoding. Mas usando a flag `u` vc força a regex a usar UTF-8: `preg_replace('/([qpç]+)/iu', '</u>$1<u>', $texto);` - veja a diferença: [com a flag](https://ideone.com/MQharr) e [sem a flag](https://ideone.com/bEFD3O). E +1 atrasado - ontem comentei, fui dormir e esqueci de votar :-)

Comment: O @hkotsubo tem razão, erro meu em não deixar mais observações, mas essa resposta agrega a questão. Obrigado.

Comment: Outro detalhe é que, pelo que entendi [deste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/397725#comment781456_397725), ele só quer as letras minúsculas, então é melhor remover a *flag* `i` da regex

Comment: @hkotsubo valeu! Vou editar!

Comment: @hkotsubo não sabia da flag `U`, eu estava tentando fazer um enconde para utf8... kkk Valeu!

Comment: Só lembrando que a flag é `u` minúsculo. O `U` maiúsculo também existe, mas faz outra coisa: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php